# i have a floating button in main activity.i want to clear all fragments and return to Main Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a floating button in main activity.i want to clear all fragments and return to Main Activity.my code is working when i am in Fragment A it returns on activity but but from Fragment B it returns to Fragment A not in Main Activity..plz guide me.
My floating button Code is here

```
FloatingActionButton bt_home = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.home);
    bt_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.myFrame);
            if (fragment != null) {

                fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
   //                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFrame)).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Brother you are already in the activity. The thing you are missing is just know that fragment is a part of activity, it's just a view in an activity. so all you can do is just make one fragment which is your home fragment and get back to that fragment.

Comment: I knew it..but i want to clear all fragments in Activity and get the actual layout of my main activity..Is it possible@DushyantSuthar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trick is simply you start main activity on FloatingActionButton  onClick event

```
        bt_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MAinActivity.class));
             //or start home fragment
         Fragment home = new HomeFragment();
         FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
         FM.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, home).commit();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry i am already in main activity....I just want to clear all fragments on single click..

Comment: if you in main activity then start home fragment again

Comment: first fragment...thats is default fragment on Activity created.

Comment: replace homefragment by your first fragment